# Create a dashboard by aligning multiple browser windows - is there a browser with no controls, icons, nothing?

Tags: web-browser, dashboard

Currently, if I align multiple browser windows together, a lot of screen real-estate will be taken by the buttons.

Is there a way to have content only?

Just like full-screen mode (only browser) but without a full screen.

Comment: maybe this may work ... https://electronjs.org/

Comment: I've heard about it and one thing I've noticed - the "Hello World" was 300 MB because of the whole Chromium engine bundled... Interesting thought, with some dev skills it can be a clever workaround.

Comment: https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-frameless-window/